# How to execute batch file silently in windows background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, batch-file

i have a batch file which helps to start my rails server.when i am starting my batch file the command prompt is opening but here i need the cmd should not visible to user or it will execute at windows background.I am explaining mt `.bat` file code below.

```
c:
cd c:\\Site\swargadwara_puri

rails server
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it silently using a Vbscript file instead. The Run Method allows you running a script in invisible mode. Create a .vbs file like this one :

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyBatchFile
MyBatchFile = "C:\New Floder\toto 1.bat"
Call Run(MyBatchFile,1,False) 'Showing the console
Call Run(MyBatchFile,0,False) 'Hidding the console
'*********************************************************************************
Function Run(MyBatchFile,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        Result = ws.run(DblQuote(MyBatchFile),Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        Result = ws.run(DblQuote(MyBatchFile),Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

The second argument in this example sets the window style. 0 means "hide the window, and 1 means "show the window"

Complete syntax of the [Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx):

```
 object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

**Arguments:**

- object: WshShell object.
- strCommand: String value indicating the command line you want to run. You must include any parameters you want to pass to the executable file.
- intWindowStyle: Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this information.
- bWaitOnReturn: Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after     starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the batch command, for example using:

```
START /MIN rails server
```